# Is the ARRAffinity cookie always set in azure web applications?

Tags: azure, session, iis, azure-web-app-service

I a host web application on Azure. I have a basic plan where only one instance works. After I've published my app into cloud, I've noticed an automatically generated cookie called `ARRAffinity`. So even with single instance of hosted web application there will be always generated `ARRAffinity` cookie? Is that right? Or it doesn't matter how many instances are around and the Azure web application always generates the cookie?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's always there by default.
There are ways to [Disable Session affinity cookie (ARR cookie) for Azure web apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/disabling-arrs-instance-affinity-in-windows-azure-web-sites/)

Here's an explanation: [Azure: ARRAffinity makes affinity cookies!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devschool/2015/06/19/azure-arraffinity-makes-affinity-cookies/)

> Affinity Cookies are used to aid people who need to stay with a certain instance of web app or web site in Azure.  The reason for this is that we strive for statelessness, but do not always achieve it.  This means that the user must stay on the particular instance that they using till they break state and then things are saved at that time.

Answer (score 6):

This can be disabled without adding the `Arr-Disable-Session-Affinity` header that was mentioned in the blog post in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50741182/10615308). Azure has an option to turn this off under Settings > Configuration > General Settings > Platform settings.

[image: The setting toggle in Azure]